# Full page responsive image with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, html5-canvas

i am trying the image to cover full page.

Vertical scroll : allowed

Horizontal scrolling : disallowed

Image : image must show full page without leaving border and responsive based on device size.

```css
html, body, img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
<img src="example.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

The issues is, it leaving a blank space in all 4 side of the screen. How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may Help you :

```
 *{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    }

    img{
    width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: works cool. defining height is not important? like min-height or high 100%?

Comment: Not because you need : Vertical scroll : allowed

Comment: yes but if the image is small it wont cover whole page if `min-height` is not defined?

Comment: In that case min-height defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background image property
Check here - [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-image)

Comment: it possible to make background image clickable with a href tag?

Comment: So u mean when you click the href tag, you want to display the background image right?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset the browser added styles to the body tag by removing the padding and margin from it, feel free to add this at the top of your styles:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This works. it cancel the edges space but still the image is not responsive for resizing the screen after loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to cover full page, better use background-image and background-size cover, using this way your aspect ratio is also maintained

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
 background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```